# Checking server after an infinite sql query that ran 534,004 times

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

So I had an incident a few minutes ago where I used a while loop and did not increment anything.  I changed over to a for loop that stopped the infinite loop.  I just want to know how to check the server to make sure it is working properly after I dropped the table that was getting added to over 500,000 times.

I'm working on a LAMP server with apache2.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you just shut it down and restart it? Which is how I've dealt with bad loops in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

This will list all running processes with an `id`

you then run

`KILL id`

Where `id` is the `id` of the process you want to stop